# Area of revolution of a square

Tags: geometry, visualization

A square of side length 1 is rotated 360 degrees about one of its vertices. What is the area of the region the square covers while rotating?

I don't know how to visualize this as a geometric shape that I can find the area of. Can someone help?

Comment: 1) What angle does the diagonal make to the axis of revolution?    2) Are the diagonal and axis in the same plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite vertex is the farthest point from the vertex as the centre of rotation. The region is the circle with the diagonal joining the two vertices as a radius.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the square sides and axis are in the same plane then we have

*two cones and two cone frustums* connecting them

2) If two far off sides (not connected to sides in contact with  axis) are skewed (not in the same plane) then we have

*two cones and two segments of one-sheet hyperboloids* connecting them.

3) If the plane of square is perpendicular to the rotation axis then we have

*a circular sheet radius $\sqrt2$*

Images can be uploaded if you so wish.